# Virtual Method that returns <this>?

Tags: ida, c++

In my vtable i found a method that simply returns ecx.
Now im confused as to what this tries to accomplish ? 
Is this a known useful sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ compiler of Visual Studio uses `ecx` as the default register for `this` pointer, a virtual method which returns `ecx` then actually returns `this` or `*this`. For example, you can test the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual A getmyself() { return *this; }
  virtual A* getmyselfpointer() { return this; }
}
```

The generated assembly code for `getmyself` (the same for `getmyselfpointer`) is

```
getmyself:
  mov     eax, ecx
  retn
```

This detail is not true for `clang` or `gcc` since they do not use `ecx` as default register for `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a method that at a high-level is intended to return a [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) object pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If it would be ARM I'd say that it is constructor or destructor (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452133/arm-c-abi-constructor-destructor-return-values) for more details). As a part of more general pattern I had seen such a things in a multi-platform applications where the main code of the function was `#ifdef`'ed out and only return value was left for compatibility with other platforms/build configurations.

Did you see calls to this function?